# Error: Invalid field 'size' for SObject 'OpportunityLineItem'

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I would like to check the size of the `OpportunityLineItem` related list in a `Visualforce Email Template` like below, where `relatedTo` is an `Opportunity`

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems.size != 0}">
```

But I get error:

> Error: Invalid field 'size' for SObject 'OpportunityLineItem'.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `relatedTo` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to get the `size` directly in `visualforce` email template, for that you will have to use the repeat tag to get the count and then you can build further logic based on that variable.

```
<apex:variable var="sizeOfOpportunityLineItem" value="{!0}"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}">
    <apex:variable var="sizeOfOpportunityLineItem" value="{!sizeOfOpportunityLineItem + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
Number of Opportunity Line Items : {!sizeOfOpportunityLineItem}
```

Comment: This is not a `Visualforce Page` its an `Visualforce Email Template` I don't have a controller

Comment: Updated the answer, that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. It works. But I will be honest, I am not keen on the solution, it seem unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Yup I can understand, but AFAIK there is no other way. @sfdcfox : Can you please see if this can be done in a better and simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your OpportunityLineItems is an OpportunityLineItem instead of a List.

Comment: But I am using `OpportunityLineItems` not `OpportunityLineItem`